# How to limit a full join by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

Our database is on SQL Server 2014. I had the exact same issue as [SQL join table to itself to get data for previous year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372649/sql-join-table-to-itself-to-get-data-for-previous-year?answertab=votes#tab-top), and was so happy to find the answer. So I setup my query:

```
select distinct 
    coalesce (a.year, b.year+1) [Year]
  , coalesce(a.Month, b.Month) [Month]
  , coalesce(a.account, b.account) [Account]
  , case when a.sales > 0
        then a.sales
        else 0 end [Sales MTD]
  , case when b.sales > 0
        then b.sales
        else 0 end [Sales Previous Year]
  , (case when b.sales!= 0
        then cast((case when a.sales > 0
                then a.sales
                else 0 end-b.sales)/b.sales*100 as decimal(10,1))
        else 0 end) [% Difference]
  , sum(a.sales) over (Partition by a.account, a.year order by a.month) [Account Sales YTD]
from yourtable a
      full join yourtable b 
            on  a.account = b.account
            and a.month = b.month
            and a.year = b.year+1
```

The output is giving me results for months in 2022 that haven't happened yet (and starting 2023 too). https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9a2c29f1af08f525a1acee16b0efa2fd

I tried adding `and b.[year]+1<=year(getdate())` to my join filters, but that doesn't seem to affect output at all. I also tried writing a where clause, that ended up with a case that made my head spin.

How can I prevent future dates from showing up in the end result?
Bonus question: Can I make my YTD calculation accept a 0 as a value for any lines added due to sales history?

Comment: Regarding YTD, are you looking only for the positive values as with MTD?

Comment: @shawnt00, essentially yes, though the source table is only sales, and doesn't have any negative values.

Comment: That doesn't really explain anything and it doesn't explain the test for `sales > 0`.

Comment: using it the same as `sales is not null` but fewer characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause

```
... 
where datefromparts(coalesce(a.year, b.year+1), coalesce(a.Month, b.Month), 1) <= cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: This does at least keep it to this year, though still shows future months

Comment: Good point. And a date can be created from a year and month. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Narrow the list of relevant rows prior to doing the full join.

```
with A as (
    select *
    from tableA
    where ...
), B as (
    select *
    from tableB
    where ...
)
select * from A full outer join B on ...
```

You could also just do this inline:

```
select *
from
    (select * from tableA where ...) as A
    full outer join
    (select * from tableB where ...) as B
```

**EDIT:** If you "pre-filter" the data within relevant dates you don't need to do the awkward coalesced checks later:

```
with A as (
    select year, month, account, sales
    from yourtable
    -- if there's no future data then this whole cte may be unnecessary
    where year < year(getdate())
       or year = year(getdate()) and month <= month(getdate())
), B as (
    select year + 1 as year, month, account, sales
    from yourtable 
    where year < year(getdate()) - 1
       or year = year(getdate()) - 1 and month <= month(getdate())
)
select
    coalesce(a.year, b.year) [Year]
  , coalesce(a.Month, b.Month) [Month]
  , coalesce(a.account, b.account) [Account]
  , sum(a.sales) over (Partition by a.account, a.year order by a.month) [Account Sales YTD]  
from A full outer join B
    on  a.account = b.account
    and a.month = b.month
    and a.year = b.year
order by 1, 2
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=26c30b190d475d8679f2253a3c428f1f

Comment: I think this still get's me in the weeds of a where statement like
`where case when  tableB.year +1 >= YEAR(getdate())
then tableB.month <= MONTH(getdate())
else tableB.month <= 13 end`

Answer (score 0):

if I've understood correctly, you need a left outer join, as you care when you have records in one table but not both.

Comment: Unfortunately left outer joins won't create the lines I need to show months that had no sales in a displayed year, but did have sales a previous year.