# How to get top 10 data weekly (This week, Previous week, Last month, 2 months ago, 3 month ago)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-limit, sql-rank

I want to retrieve the Top 10 Products - weekly

```
Rank     This week product   Previous week rank   Last month rank   2 month ago rank     3 month ago rank
 1             Watch                  2                    3                    1               4
 2             Radio                  3                    2                    4               5
 3             Pen                    4                    5                    6               7
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
```

Please help me with how to get this type of data from SQL queries. Thanks

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for the table(s); the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; a complete description of the problem including how the ranks should be calculated; the expected output for the sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution. If we don't know what data you have or how the ranks should be calculated then we either would have to guess or we cannot answer the question; please help us to help you by giving a complete question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372649/sql-join-table-to-itself-to-get-data-for-previous-year?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  product          VARCHAR2(20),
  some_date_column DATE
)
```

Then you can use conditional aggregation inside the `RANK` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT product,
       RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN some_date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
           AND  some_date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY
           THEN 1
           END
         ) DESC
       ) AS rank_this_week,
       RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN some_date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY
           AND  some_date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW')
           THEN 1
           END
         ) DESC
       ) AS rank_last_week,
       RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN some_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), -1)
           AND  some_date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM')
           THEN 1
           END
         ) DESC
       ) AS rank_last_month,
       RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN some_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), -2)
           AND  some_date_column <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), -1)
           THEN 1
           END
         ) DESC
       ) AS rank_two_month,
       RANK() OVER (
         ORDER BY COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN some_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), -3)
           AND  some_date_column <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), -2)
           THEN 1
           END
         ) DESC
       ) AS rank_three_month
FROM   your_table
WHERE  some_date_column < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') + INTERVAL '7' DAY
AND    some_date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW'), -3)
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY rank_this_week
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (product, some_date_column)
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'G', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  7 UNION ALL
SELECT 'H', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  8 UNION ALL
SELECT 'I', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  9 UNION ALL
SELECT 'J', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 'K', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  7 UNION ALL
SELECT 'G', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  6 UNION ALL
SELECT 'H', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  4 UNION ALL
SELECT 'I', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  5 UNION ALL
SELECT 'J', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'K', TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - INTERVAL '7' DAY FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  2
-- Etc.
```

*(Note: this only has data for the last 2 weeks so all the other ranks will be ties.)*

Outputs:

> | PRODUCT | RANK_THIS_WEEK | RANK_LAST_WEEK | RANK_LAST_MONTH | RANK_TWO_MONTH | RANK_THREE_MONTH |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | K | 1 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | J | 2 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | I | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | H | 4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | G | 5 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | F | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | E | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | D | 8 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | C | 9 | 11 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
> | B | 10 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f073bd0d920127439694df269d25ca58)*